# PHP get some data from database then echo it out into a JS file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

**MYSQL table structure:**
id , name , status , color

how can i use PHP to get some data from my database(mysql) ,the php script will look for table rows that have **"good"** in the **"status"** column. Then echo those rows which have good in status(P/S  out into  a JS file. It also get the color from each row (with status=good) and ptu it into javascript(jQUery)

I did a little research on how to use php to generate javascript.

Here's a php script, it's not working btw:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

  include 'connect.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status ='good'"; 
  $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

  $rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )){
  $rows[] = $row;
  echo "$('a[href*=\"row[username]\"]').css('color', 'row[color]');\n";
}

?>
```

The out put is (which wont work):

```
$('a[href*="row[username]"]').css('color', 'row[color]');
```

The connect.php is working(connects to database) , just the script is not working.

(BTW: The file name of this is **usercolor.js.php** , is it correct?)
I hope someone could guide me.

Thanks and have a wonderful day.

Comment: `just the script is not working.` - in what way is it not working? No output, the javascript is invalid, etc etc - give us a clue!

Comment: Check the output of the script and add it to your question.

Comment: sorry about that , i've edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$('a[href*=\"row[username]\"]').css('color', 'row[color]');\n";
```

won't work. Try

```
$username = $row['username'];
$color = $row['color']; 
echo "$('a[href*=\"$username\"]').css('color', '$color');\n";
```

or

```
echo "$('a[href*=\"{$row['username']}\"]').css('color', '{$row['color']}');\n";
```

see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for an explanation. Also, according to your mysql table structure, the column is called name and not username.

Comment: @roman there is a syntax error in your code. Hence my edit. Please refrain from rolling back to broken code.

Comment: @Treffynnon oh, I didn't rollback intentionally, we just edited at the same time. Thanks anyway for correcting the typo.

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys , selected as answer